# Go Backend unable to connect to postgres instance

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, kubernetes

I have a postgres instance installed on a cluster and I am able to exec into the pod and work with the DB. I have a simple Go application to interact with the Postgres, The program runs as intended, the following is the connection string of my Go application:

```golang
    db, err = sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://santosh:dts123@localhost:5432/bookstore?")
```

But, when I containerze the application and run it or add it to a pod, the pod stays in `CrashLoopBackOff` and it is unable to connect to the Postgres and when I try to exec into the container or run the container, I am getting the following result:

```
santosh@frontend*$:k logs -n frontend-api bookstore-frontend-7c68888df6-7nsx4 -c bookstore
panic: dial tcp [::1]:5432: connect: connection refused

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /home/main.go:41 +0x2d2
```

I have a service infront of the postgres pod:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres 
  namespace: database
  labels:
    app: postgres 
spec:
  type: NodePort 
  ports:
    - port: 5432
  selector:
    app: bookstore
```

In the backend depployment, I have routed the `POSTGRES_HOST` as the FQDN of the service with port `postgres.database.svc:5432` in the configMap, the configmap and deployment is as follows:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: frontend-cm
  namespace: frontend-api
data:
  dbHost: postgres.database:5432 
  dbName: bookstore
  sslMode: disable
```

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: bookstore-frontend
  name: bookstore-frontend
  namespace: frontend-api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bookstore-frontend
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bookstore-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: docker.io/santoshdts/bookstore:build-1
        name: bookstore
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
        env:
          - name: POSTGRES_SSLMODE
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: frontend-cm
                key: sslMode
          - name: POSTGRES_HOST
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: frontend-cm
                key: dbHost
          - name: POSTGRES_DB
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: frontend-cm
                key: dbName
          - name: POSTGRES_USER
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: frontend-secret
                key: dbUser
          - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: frontend-secret
                key: dbPassword
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

Is this issue related to some misconfiguration in the env variables? I have some data in the DB, so the backend is trying to connect to an existing DB. Hence, the env names I've used like `POSTGRES_*` is valid for this workflow or I need to specify the variales as `PG*` format as [explained here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html)?

Or my backend Go application needs some amendment?

can someone please help me on this.
Thank you!

I've tried installing the `wbitt/network-multitool` to debug the connections and when I try to NSLookup the svc, I get:

```
/ # nslookup postgres.database.svc
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Name:   postgres.database.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.96.11.156
```

and when I curl the postgres instance, I get the empty response:

```
/ # curl postgres.database.svc:5432
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

The logs aren't helping much,as the container is in `CrashLoopBackOff`. The postgres pod logs are as below:

```
santosh@frontend*$:k logs -n database postgres-75fb5c858d-pswdn 

PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

2022-11-22 06:23:08.306 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.1 (Debian 15.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2022-11-22 06:23:08.306 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2022-11-22 06:23:08.306 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2022-11-22 06:23:08.308 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-11-22 06:23:08.312 UTC [34] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-11-21 19:25:23 UTC
2022-11-22 06:23:08.336 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2022-11-22 06:28:08.412 UTC [32] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2022-11-22 06:28:08.521 UTC [32] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 4 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.103 s, sync=0.002 s, total=0.109 s; sync files=3, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB
2022-11-22 06:39:44.421 UTC [88] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2022-11-22 07:15:46.705 UTC [197] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2022-11-22 07:19:31.744 UTC [225] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2022-11-22 07:32:01.716 UTC [263] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2022-11-22 07:32:12.053 UTC [265] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2022-11-22 08:12:27.927 UTC [386] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2022-11-22 08:47:25.072 UTC [492] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
```

Comment: Can you try changing Postgres host to `postgres.database.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: Where is your cluster deployed? Is it on some cloud or self managed?

Comment: It's an on-prem test cluster on Kind.

Comment: Do you have DNS configured for Kubernetes in your cluster, it may be CoreDNS or any other. You can check by listing all pods

Comment: @TekNathAcharya I tried a `curl` on the `postgres.database.svc.cluster.local` that doesn't reply anything, but If add the port at the end `:5432` I get an `empty reply from server`

Comment: Yes, Kind comes pre-installed with `CoreDNS` as a deployment.

Comment: May be you can spin up a ubuntu pod and instal Postgres client there and try to connect and debug the issue

Comment: Looks like it’s an issue with connection string of my application. The localhost is not `127.0.0.1` but the docker one `172.17.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resloved my issue. The problem was with my connection string in the Go application. I replaced the `dbhost` parameter from `localhost` to the fqdn of the service, in my case it was: `postgres.database.svc.cluster.local`.